# Correct capitalization of strings

Tags: php, libraries

I have a thousands of Strings I want to capitalize them correctly

default String Capitalization can change
"world war ii" -> "World War Ii"

or

"usa" -> "Usa"
is there any other kind of smart Capitalization solution for it?

Comment: The only way is using a dictionary.. Better search in Google for some ready solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything to make a smart string capitalization on your own or tried a library different than builtins?

Comment: Is your question about Swift or about PHP?

Comment: Marting R I was wondering to make it client side or server side

Answer (score 5):

i am not sure why your question is downvoted. Anyway, please see the below function and adjust according to your requirements

```
function titleCase($string) 
{
    $word_splitters = array(' ', '-', "O'", "L'", "D'", 'St.', 'Mc');
    $lowercase_exceptions = array('the', 'van', 'den', 'von', 'und', 'der', 'de', 'da', 'of', 'and', "l'", "d'");
    $uppercase_exceptions = array('III', 'IV', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX');

    $string = strtolower($string);
    foreach ($word_splitters as $delimiter)
    { 
        $words = explode($delimiter, $string); 
        $newwords = array(); 
        foreach ($words as $word)
        { 
            if (in_array(strtoupper($word), $uppercase_exceptions))
                $word = strtoupper($word);
            else
            if (!in_array($word, $lowercase_exceptions))
                $word = ucfirst($word); 

            $newwords[] = $word;
        }

        if (in_array(strtolower($delimiter), $lowercase_exceptions))
            $delimiter = strtolower($delimiter);

        $string = join($delimiter, $newwords); 
    } 
    return $string; 
}
```

Originally mentioned @ [here](http://www.media-division.com/correct-name-capitalization-in-php/)

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: thanks that is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the php function [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

```
string ucwords ( string $str [, string $delimiters = " \t\r\n\f\v" ] )
```

Hope this helps